# Converting decimal to binary and then binary to unknown format?

Tags: c#, java, number-formatting

I am using an API which gives me result in 32 bit(4 byte) data.I need to decode this value to another format to use it.

An example of data could be:

```
 645 --> (00000000 00000000 00000010 10000101) --> (0, 0, 2, 133)
```

I will receive 645 from API which I need to first convert to binary format and then to an unknown format which I am not able to understand.I am able to convert "645" to binary format using the below code :

```
   public static void toBinary(String value){
       int i = Integer.parseInt(value);
       System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
   }
```

**output : 100000000000000000**

But how do I get it to `(0,0,2,133)` to use it in my application.Could anyone please help me telling which format is this?

Comment: That's the base 10 format (decimal) of the individual digits.

Comment: Are you working in Java or C#?

Comment: I am working in java but added the C# tag as well because its a common question

Comment: What is the unknown format for? You need to do the conversion and then send the formatted output somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, 645 in base 2 is 1010000101. (Your code gives an incorrect result for some reason).

Once you realize that, I think it's fairly simple to see that the "unknown format" can be reached by simply breaking the binary value into chunks of 8 bits (adding 0's at the beginning where necessary) to give your intermediate binary format, and then converting each chunk (byte) into decimal (base 10).

`00000000` in base 10 is 0. `00000010` in base 10 is 2. `10000101` in base 10 is 133.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
String s = "(" + (n >> 24 & 0xFF) + ", " + (n >> 16 & 0xFF)+ ", " + (n >> 8 & 0xFF)+ ", " + (n & 0xFF) + ")";
```

Comment: Yes, OP, this is how to do exactly what you are asking (formatted as a String).

Comment: @Evgeniy I am not able to understand what you have posted as answer.Please help how do I use this?